# Swift Mailer sending only last row of table

Tags: php, mysql, swiftmailer

I am pulling email addresses from a database table and iterating through them to send an email. If I comment out the line `$mailer->send($message);` an email is sent out, but only to the last row in the table. If I leave that line in, the email is sent to all recipients, but sends twice to the last row in the table. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <?php

    // Pull the data from the database
    $query = "SELECT emailAddress, firstName, lastName FROM test_table";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query))
    {
        /* Put the data into an array */
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $swimmers[] = $row;
        }

        /* free result set */
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }

    /* close connection */
    mysqli_close($link);

    /* Create the replacements array */
    $replacements = array();
    foreach ($swimmers as $swimmmer) {
        $replacements[$swimmer["emailAddress"]] = array (
            "{firstName}" => $swimmer["firstName"],
            "{lastName}" => $swimmer["lastName"],
            "{fullName}" => ($swimmer["firstName"] . ' ' . $swimmer["lastName"])
        );
    }

    /* Create the Transport */
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()
        ;

    // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
    $decorator = new Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin($replacements);
    $logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $mailer->registerPlugin($decorator);
    $mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

    // Create the message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

        // Give the message a subject
        ->setSubject('STUFF')

        // Set the From address with an associative array
        ->setFrom(array('STUFF' => 'STUFF'))

        // Give it a body
        ->setBody('STUFF', 'text/html')

        // And optionally an alternative body
        ->addPart('STUFF', 'text/plain')


        // Optionally add any attachments
        ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath('STUFF'))
    ;

        // Set the To addresses with an associative array
        foreach($swimmers as $swimmer) 
        {
            echo $swimmer['emailAddress'];
            $message->setTo($swimmer["emailAddress"], $swimmer["fullName"]);
            //$mailer->send($message);
        }

    echo $logger->dump();

        // Pass a variable name to the send() method
        if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
        {
            echo "Failures:";
            print_r($failures);
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: You will probably get better answers by doing some investigation to find the specific code that isn't working as expected and asking a more specific question from there

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've been working on this for two days and have never asked a question on stackoverflow, so I spent plenty of time researching this problem before finally resorting to creating an account and asking the question. The problem is that the only two pages I could find decorator plugin code for (http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html and http://www.sitepoint.com/sending-email-with-swift-mailer/) have different approaches and no examples with php foreach loops, so I thought the issue was in my loop but could not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this function (*after the echo $logger->dump();*)

```
 if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
```

you resend the last email

the  `$mailer->send($message, $failures)` send email also if inside a if  eval

Comment: Thank you. I had taken my original one-off sendmail code and modified it for the decorator plugin. I thought that IF statement was only for logging the errors, so I didn't see the duplication there.

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you still want the controll if there is failures
//Set an empty array to hold $failures outside of your loop..
$failures=array();
foreach($swimmers as $swimmer) 
        {
            echo $swimmer['emailAddress'];
            $message->setTo($swimmer["emailAddress"], $swimmer["fullName"]);
            $mailer->send($message, $failures);  

         }
//Outside the loop controll if there is a failure..
if($failures){
    echo "Failures:<br>";
    print_r($failures);
}
```

Even better you can send multiple mails with Swiftmailer `->setTo` method..So you don't need that foreach loop..But you need a proper array for it.The all process can be simplified..

Have a look at last example at..

### http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html